# Joining two arrays together to make json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty ruby nuby so I'm sure I am doing something awful here. I'd like to join two arrays so that I can pass it to my controller where json will be created. This is the only way I can do this for reasons of the d3 library Im using and its requirements.

To do this I have the following in my controller:

```
def self.including_relationships
      result=[]
    result['nodes']=User.pluck(:name,:group)
    result['links']=Relationship.select('follower_id as source, followed_id as target, value').map{|x| [x.source, x.target, x.value]}
    result
  end
```

The controller:

```
def data
     @users = User.including_relationships
     respond_to do |format|
       #format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json {  render json: @users } 
     end
  end
```

I would like the end result, when its passed through my controller to look like:

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Child2","group":10},
    {"name":"Brujon","group":4},
    {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":62,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}
  ]
}
```

The table relationships are all correct (User to Relationship one to many). I think its just a question of how I can get the two queries into a combined format so that I can render them in json in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the JSON in required format, all you need to do is, change the Array to a Hash.

```
result = {}
```

And may be the map call like below, if you need an Array of Hashes, for links

```
map{|x| {source: x.source, target: x.target, value: x.value} }
```

Comment: So is it correct to name the two arrays result['nodes'] and result['links']

Comment: Naming is upto you. I'd have used the obvious names, `users` and `relationships`

Comment: Running this code with your corrections results in SELECT "users"."name", "users"."group" FROM "users"
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the standard serialization techniques rather than to_json which is deemed bad practice ([here's one view point)](https://blog.codepath.com/2011/05/16/if-youre-using-to_json-youre-doing-it-wrong/).

I think this is a little out of date but you'd get the idea:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers?view=asciicast

Additionally when selecting from two models you can preload the associated model which makes it a tad quicker (though joining would be best if possible):

```
User.includes([:relationships])
```

Then use the more advanced serialization techniques as shown in the video above to manage it. It also makes it less flaky and more testable in general.

Hope that helps.